# In an OCaml scanner, why does the regex for negative integers not work?

Tags: regex, ocaml, ocamllex

I have the following ocamllex code:

```
let flt = ['-' '+']?['0'-'9']+ ['.'] ['0'-'9']+
rule token = parse
  [' ' '\t' '\r' '\n']      { token lexbuf } (* Whitespace *)
| ['0'-'9']+ as lxm         { INTEGER(int_of_string lxm) }
| flt as lxm    { FLOAT(float_of_string lxm) }
```

This works!

But the minute I want to allow + and - signs for the INTEGER, it gives me an error.

```
let flt = ['-' '+']?['0'-'9']+ ['.'] ['0'-'9']+
rule token = parse
  [' ' '\t' '\r' '\n']      { token lexbuf } (* Whitespace *)
| ['+' '-']['0'-'9']+ as lxm        { INTEGER(int_of_string lxm) }
| flt as lxm    { FLOAT(float_of_string lxm) }
```

The error is as follows:

```
Fatal error: exception Failure("int_of_string")
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

The funny thing is that in my .ml file, I am using "float_of_string", but I am NOT using "int_of_string" anywhere.

Answer (score 4):

`int_of_string` does not handle leading `+` signs, so you have to take that out before you pass your string to `int_of_string`.

Comment: int_of_string doesn't and float_of_string does?

Comment: @P.C. I had to double check this right now because it surprised me as well, but yes: `float_of_string` does handle leading plusses while `int_of_string` does not.

Answer (score 0):

The regex is working fine, it's your call to `int_of_string` that is failing. You are using `int_of_string`. Look at the fourth line of either chunk of code.

sepp2k explains why you get the exception.

I don't see how you can run your program without a main, so I can't explain the undefined symbol error.

You might want to make the leading +/- optional for your integers. In your definition one of them is required.